# Why does Android prompt me with "Enter the credential storage password" when I attempt to connect to a secured WiFi network?

Tags: wi-fi, security

When I connect my iPhone to a secured WiFi network (at work), I'm prompted for my Username and Password. (And then I'm prompted to accept what I presume is an SSL certificate.)

But when I select the same network on my Motorola Droid or HTC EVO 4G, I'm prompted with "Enter the credential storage password".  What is this password?

Answer (score 5):

I went into Settings -> Location & Security (on Droid, Security on the EVO) -> Use secure credentials, and entered the credential storage password.  Then I was no longer prompted for this password when selecting the WiFi network.

Answer (score 1):

With SSL you are using the RSA public/private key pairs to securely exchange the encrypt/decrypt key for a much simpler encryption algorithm.

The RSA keys are used so you can start with the bare minimum of knowledge of each other.

The public key of the SSL cert of the server needs to be signed by someone you already trust.  Those are stored in the Trusted Root store.  Most browsers ship with all the well known ones.

If they are not trusted, you will get asked to trust them, which is probably what you are getting asked, and then to store it, so it is now 'trusted' and they do not have to ask again.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to your Settings
2. Select Security
3. And Set a 4 digit pin.

It worked for me.